# How to remove all items of array except specific one?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have a variable which is containing these nested arrays:

```
echo $var;

/* Output:
Array(
       [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 1
             [box] => 0
         )

       [2] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2
             [box] => 0
         )

       [3] => Array
         (
             [id] => 3
             [box] => 1
         )
) */
```

Now I want to remove all items of array above except `$numb = 2;` *(the value of id)*. I mean I want this output:

```
echo newvar;

/* Output:
Array(
       [2] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2
             [box] => 0
         )
) */
```

How can I do that?

---

Actually I can do a part of it by using `if` statement and `array_shift()` function:

```
foreach($var as $key => $val) {
    if($val["id"] != 2) {
        array_shift($var);
    }
}
```

But the output of code above isn't want I need.

Comment: why not just create a new array? `$cleansed = $arr[$id_you_want]; unset($arr);`? much more efficient to just copy the one element you want to keep, rather than repeatedly deleting unwanted stuff.

Comment: @MarcB emm, not bad ... thank you

Comment: is `2` the array key or the value of `id` within it?

Comment: @MarcB Just there is a problem, Sometimes array isn't containing that key I want ... Also that `2` isn't the index of array, it is the value of `id`.

Comment: @RobbieAverill the value of `id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a slightly different loop.

```
foreach ($var as $item) {
    if ($item['id'] == 2) {
        $newvar = $item;
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also use array_filter

```
$id = 2;
$newvar = array_filter($var, function($x) use ($id) { return $x['id'] == $id; });
```

but it would most likely be less efficient as it would have to check every element of the array.

Comment: Just a small note, Sometimes that number isn't exist in the array, and I want it return `null` in that case, is that possible?

Comment: If the item is not found, `$newvar` will never be set. You can initialize it to `null` before the loop.

Comment: In the filter example you'd be better to pass `2` in as a variable as I imagine it'd not a magic number, i.e. `array_filter($var, function($x) use ($id) { return $x['id'] == $id; });`

Comment: Look, I know, this isn't related to current question, but I faced a new problem. Based on my codes, I cannot define a new variable like (`$newvar`), So I cannot initialize it to `null` before the loop. Is there any workaround? I want [this](https://3v4l.org/7CnHV) returns `null` instead of all items.

Comment: @RobbieAverill agreed. Besides, if we were going to use a magic number, it should probably be _three_, rather than two.

Comment: @stack, if you need `$var` to be set that way, you can set it after the loop: `$var = isset($newvar) ? $newvar : null;`

Answer (score 4):

I'm wondering how much context would help us with answering your question... Here is an answer to what you asked:

```
$newArray = array($var[2]);
```

Comment: Simple but effective

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a new array:

```
$oldArray = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3=> 'd');

$index = 2;
$newArray = array($index => $oldArray[$index]);

// or even
$newArray = [$index => $oldArray[$index]];
```

If you don't need to preserve the index you can just do:

```
$newArray = [$oldArray[$index]];
```

Comment: Look, I update my question, actually that `2` isn't the index of array, it is the value of `id`.

Comment: In that case, it looks like `$key` is the index for your array - you can use that instead of the `$index` variable in my answer.  (e.g. `$newvar = array($var[$key]);`)

Answer (score 1):

[array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) would also do the job:

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'box' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'box' => 0],
    ['id' => 3, 'box' => 1]
];
$id = 2;
$result = array_reduce ($array, function ($carry, $item) use ($id) {
    if ( $item['id'] === $id )
        $carry[$item['id']] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, []);
```